# Connecting instance of custom ViewController to a view

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I'm working on the Card Matching Game project from Stanford's iOS course in Swift. I have two  ViewControllers on a tab bar for 2 different types of card game that push to the same View, which shows move history. I want separate move histories for each game, so created a different instance of HistoryViewController in each of the 2 game-type's ViewController. I then manipulate these instances as moves are made. How do I tell Xcode to use that specific instance of HistoryViewController when navigating from the proper parent? For example, if I am in the 1st card game and press "History", the HistoryViewController initialized in card game 1's code should be shown in the History view.

I've attached an image of the storyboard. Any help would be much appreciated :)

[image: Screenshot Of Storyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the history view controller from both view controllers.As they both will make the diffrent instance of history view controller.As both `segue` are different you can give different name to them and do `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push1", sender: self)` and  `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push2", sender: self)` or directly you can push.

You can create the `label` or `textview` for history and pass the information which you want to display in

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "push1") {
        let viewController:ViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewController
        // pass data to next view
        viewController.label = @"history for 1st view controller"
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "someanothersegue") {
       //Perform some another task for any other segue
    }
}
```

This way you can pass data to destination view controller which is history view controller  in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, since the prepareForSegue is in the parent VC the if statement isn't needed, instead I just get the destination VC and change its property. It would be nice if one could change the destination VC to a specific instance of a VC, but this works. Thanks :)